# Hyperref not working with superfullcite

Tags: biblatex, hyperref, hyperlink

I hope this is not already answered somewhere else in the forum, I have been looking for a while and I have not found anything...

The thing is I am sorting my bibliography using the superfullcite command, and it works great. However, when I use the hyperref package, the hyperlinks for every cite are broken...

Here I post a MWE...any help would be great. Thank you!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=numeric-comp]{biblatex}
\bibliography{biblatex-examples}
\makeatletter

\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{citetracker,sorting=none}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\superfullcite}[\cbx@superscript]%
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \let\multicitedelim=\supercitedelim
   \iffieldundef{prenote}
     {}
     {\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring prenote argument}}%
   \iffieldundef{postnote}
     {}
     {\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring postnote argument}}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{superfullcite}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:comp}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:dump}}

\newbibmacro*{superfullcite}{%
  \ifciteseen
    {}
    {\xappto\cbx@citehook{%
       \noexpand\footnotetext[\thefield{labelnumber}]{%
         \fullcite{\thefield{entrykey}}.}}}}

\newrobustcmd{\cbx@superscript}[1]{%
  \mkbibsuperscript{#1}%
  \cbx@citehook
  \global\let\cbx@citehook=\empty}
\let\cbx@citehook=\empty

\makeatother

\usepackage{hyperref,bookmark}
\begin{document}

Some filler text,\superfullcite{augustine} then some more
text.\superfullcite{companion} Perhaps some more text and the
same citation again.\superfullcite{companion} Yet another
one.\superfullcite{kastenholz} Now all
again.\superfullcite{augustine,companion,kastenholz}


\newpage

And now...\superfullcite{augustine}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It may be useful to point out that the code as shown uses the normal code for numerical citations to typeset the supercites. `biblatex` usually just links the citation to the bibliography entry. You don't have a bibliography (`\printbibliography`) in your document, so the links don't attach to anything. Ulrike's answer redirects those links to the bibliograph items in the footnotes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing destinations for the links.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=numeric-comp]{biblatex}
\bibliography{biblatex-examples}
\usepackage{l3pdf}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\pdf_uncompress:
\ExplSyntaxOff
\makeatletter

\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{citetracker,sorting=none}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\superfullcite}[\cbx@superscript]%
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \let\multicitedelim=\supercitedelim
   \iffieldundef{prenote}
     {}
     {\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring prenote argument}}%
   \iffieldundef{postnote}
     {}
     {\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring postnote argument}}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{superfullcite}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:comp}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:dump}}

\newrobustcmd\superfullcitedest[1]{%
  \raisebox{\baselineskip}[0pt][0pt]{\makebox[0pt][l]{%
         \hypertarget{cite.\the\c@refsection @#1}{}\hspace{-\parindent}}}}

\newbibmacro*{superfullcite}{%
  \ifciteseen
    {}
    {\xappto\cbx@citehook{%
       \noexpand\footnotetext[\thefield{labelnumber}]{%
         \superfullcitedest{\thefield{entrykey}}%
         \fullcite{\thefield{entrykey}}.}}}}

\newrobustcmd{\cbx@superscript}[1]{%
  \mkbibsuperscript{#1}%
  \cbx@citehook
  \global\let\cbx@citehook=\empty}
\let\cbx@citehook=\empty

\makeatother

\usepackage{hyperref,bookmark}
\begin{document}

Some filler text,\superfullcite{augustine} then some more
text.\superfullcite{companion} Perhaps some more text and the
same citation again.\superfullcite{companion} Yet another
one.\superfullcite{kastenholz} Now all
again.\superfullcite{augustine,companion,kastenholz}


\newpage

And now...\superfullcite{augustine}


\end{document}
```

Comment: This solved the problem. Thank you very much!!

Comment: Just wanted to get it working with the base `\fullcite`. Got it working with `\newrobustcmd*\fullcitehyper[1]{\hypertarget{cite.\the\c@refsection @#1}\protect\fullcite{#1}}`

Answer (score 1):

Normally, `biblatex` links citations to the respective entry in the bibliography. In the MWE you don't have a bibliography, so `biblatex` doesn't create any links. (You can see how things normally work by adding a `\printbibliography` to the MWE).

As an alternative to Ulrike's answer, here is a solution that uses `biblatex` commands to set the anchor that is normally set by the bibliography entry in the fullcite.

The main idea of this approach is a copy of `\fullcite` that says `\blx@anchor` before the executing the bibliography driver.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=numeric-comp]{biblatex}


\makeatletter
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{citetracker,sorting=none}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\superfullcite}[\cbx@superscript]%
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \let\multicitedelim=\supercitedelim
   \iffieldundef{prenote}
     {}
     {\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring prenote argument}}%
   \iffieldundef{postnote}
     {}
     {\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring postnote argument}}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{superfullcite}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:comp}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:dump}}


\newbibmacro*{superfullcite}{%
  \ifciteseen
    {}
    {\xappto\cbx@citehook{%
       \noexpand\footnotetext[\thefield{labelnumber}]{%
         \superfullcite@fullcite{\thefield{entrykey}}.}}}}

\newrobustcmd{\cbx@superscript}[1]{%
  \mkbibsuperscript{#1}%
  \cbx@citehook
  \global\let\cbx@citehook=\empty}
\let\cbx@citehook=\empty

\DeclareCiteCommand{\superfullcite@fullcite}
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usedriver
     {\blx@anchor
      \DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}}
     {\thefield{entrytype}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
\makeatother



\usepackage{hyperref,bookmark}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
Some filler text,\superfullcite{augustine} then some more
text.\superfullcite{companion} Perhaps some more text and the
same citation again.\superfullcite{companion} Yet another
one.\superfullcite{kastenholz} Now all
again.\superfullcite{augustine,companion,kastenholz}


\newpage

And now...\superfullcite{augustine}
\end{document}
```